# How to organise an equation in Python differently?

Tags: python

I have a simple math manipulation question, where I have 6 variables a,b,c,d,e,f. I can only input (only know) 2 of these variables (at least) and I need the answer for all values by following 3 rules:

```
a = d/e
b = f/e
c = f/d
```

How can I write code in Python that would prioritise based on the knowledge it has (the 2 variables that happened at the time and I input) to follow one of these divisions first, and then can conclude the others from there?

I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: Why are you not using Python 3? Python 2 is outdated.

Comment: Can you show a specific example of what the input and output of the program should be?

Comment: Looks like b=d in that system of equations.

Comment: What does this have to do with Python?  Which 2 variables are known? Looks like `d` and `f` are the priors and that `c` is completely unused.

Comment: Hi Wyck. c is now there. https://github.com/rabebo/Hematology. Here is the link for github if you need to check the actual problem. a,b,c,d,e,f are by different names. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Sympy](https://reliability.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Solving%20simultaneous%20equations%20with%20sympy.html#solving-simultaneous-equations-with-sympy) for that.

```
import sympy as sym
a,b,c,d,e,f = sym.symbols('a,b,c,d,e,f')
eq1 = sym.Eq(d/e, a)
eq2 = sym.Eq(f/e, b)
eq3 = sym.Eq(f/d, e)
```

Now enter the variables you know into `sym.solve`:

```
result = sym.solve([eq1, eq2, eq3],(a, b))
print(result)
```

Output:

```
{a: d/e, b: f/e}
```

Or:

```
result = sym.solve([eq1, eq2, eq3],(d, a))
print(result)
```

Output:

```
{d: f/e, a: f/e**2}
```

Comment: Hi BioGeek. I know this is closed do you think this is moving in the right direction.https://github.com/rabebo/Hematology

Comment: @basem Please create a new question if you have a specific question or error. If you want others to review your code, please create a post at [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).